# Multisite - each site with it's own set of users

Tags: multisite, hooks, users

I'm looking for a way to separate user accounts per blog/sub-site.
I concocted a plan to hook into login/registration process and append the blog_id to the username and email upon one of these actions.
I'm not using any of the default WordPress forms for user management, but have custom ajax functionality that would require just a couple of ajax endpoints to be modified.

Would appreciate your point of view on this:
username_2
email@email.com_2
admin_2
admin@email.com_2
admin_1
admin@email.com_1

Comment: I don't think changing data inputed by user is a good idea, if you change email how will them be allowed to recover a lost password for example? What you ask for is somehow built-in since the wp_usermeta table contains references to the blog IDS to which user are associated ..something like `blog_3_user_level` `blog_2_capabilities` and so on. So combining the creation of a new user (see [WP add user programmatically](https://tommcfarlin.com/create-a-user-in-wordpress/) and the function [add_user_to_blog](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_to_blog/) will do the job

Comment: But it will not allow user A to create account on site 2 if that same user A has an email on site 1.
I'm currently trying to hook into every email hook to remove the suffix before email is sent.
My first requirement is to even allow users to register at site 2 if they (unknowingly) registered their email/username at site 1 before.

Comment: Wp_meta and wp_usermeta are shared tables, one user can have access to one or more blogs with the same credentials

Comment: I mean wp_user not wp_meta

Comment: But I have a multi-site with domain mapping, so users are unaware of the same-siteness, they see 2 separate domains when they approach the site, and if some user attempts to register on domain-a.com, then after a month or two tries to do the same at domain-b.com, (s)he will be put away with a message like "your email is already registered" but will have no connection to the fact that it's actually a multi-site with shared user table.